# Changing the shape of the window from rectangle to other shapes in macOS, It is possible?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-form

Now I'm learning on SwiftUI.

What I want to do is make window as Hexagon or circle. For putting this app with opacity on edge of the display beautifully.

But the only thing I can do is making it as square. Like many apps have been.

This is possible?

Then what should I do? Please give me some advices.

Sorry for my poor English. Thank you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Window is always rectangular, but you can make it have transparent background, hide titlebar, and then draw in content view whatever visual shape you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a borderless NSWindow and host a view with NSHostingView.

Comment: Now I droped my project, But I really appreciate you for your help.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: See my [GitHub project](https://github.com/smic/BorderlessWindow) as example